# android java xml, ids arent being recognized

Tags: java, android, xml

so this is my xml file http://grab.by/uzru (its a screenshot)
as you can see i created new ids        android:id="@+I\id/bresults"
but in my activity i cant call those ids       (R.id.(doesnt show up with my new ids)) 
This is my activity file http://grab.by/uzrG (screenshot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change :`android:id="@+I\id/bresults"` to `android:id="@+id/bresults"`

then **save** the xml file

Comment: it worked thanks i will accept in 2 minutes it has a timeframe for me to be able to accept